# determine which radio button is selected - custom radio button markup

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to determine which radio button is selected in a radio button group, on click of that group. My markup and CSS is custom made for this particular radio button and I think it might be causing issues with my click event. I have some conditional logic in javascript, where both alerts are appearing on click. Anyone have an idea on how to correct this?

Here is a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kakd8sgz/1/) of the issue.

Markup

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="toggle" id="family-radio-btn">
        <input type="radio" class="toggle-input" name="family" id="family-yes" checked>
        <label for="family-yes" class="toggle-label toggle-label-off">Yes</label>
        <input type="radio" class="toggle-input" name="family" id="family-no">
        <label for="family-no" class="toggle-label toggle-label-on">No</label>
        <span class="toggle-selection"></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
$('#family-radio-btn').click(function () {
    if ($('#family-yes:checked').length) {
        alert("yes");
    }
    else
    {
        alert("no");
    }
});
```

CSS

```
.toggle {
  position: relative;
  height: 34px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  background: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
.toggle .toggle-input {
  display: none;
}
.toggle .toggle-input:checked + .toggle-label {
  color: #ffffff;
}
.toggle .toggle-input:checked + .toggle-label-on ~ .toggle-selection {
  left: 49%;
}
.toggle .toggle-label {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  line-height: 32px;
  color: #555555;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: normal;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.toggle .toggle-label.toggle-label-off {
  padding-left: 2px;
}
.toggle .toggle-label.toggle-label-on {
  padding-right: 2px;
}
.toggle .toggle-selection {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 2px;
  left: 2px;
  display: block;
  width: 50%;
  height: 28px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: #0071bc;
  -webkit-transition: left 0.15s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: left 0.15s ease-out;
  -ms-transition: left 0.15s ease-out;
  -o-transition: left 0.15s ease-out;
  transition: left 0.15s ease-out;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
    $('input[type="radio"]').click(function (e) {
        if ($('#family-yes:checked').length) {
            console.log("yes");
        }
        else
        {
            console.log("no");
        }
        
    });
```

```css
.toggle {
  position: relative;
  height: 34px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  background: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
.toggle .toggle-input {
  display: none;
}
.toggle .toggle-input:checked + .toggle-label {
  color: #ffffff;
}
.toggle .toggle-input:checked + .toggle-label-on ~ .toggle-selection {
  left: 49%;
}
.toggle .toggle-label {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  line-height: 32px;
  color: #555555;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: normal;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.toggle .toggle-label.toggle-label-off {
  padding-left: 2px;
}
.toggle .toggle-label.toggle-label-on {
  padding-right: 2px;
}
.toggle .toggle-selection {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 2px;
  left: 2px;
  display: block;
  width: 50%;
  height: 28px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: #0071bc;
  -webkit-transition: left 0.15s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: left 0.15s ease-out;
  -ms-transition: left 0.15s ease-out;
  -o-transition: left 0.15s ease-out;
  transition: left 0.15s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="toggle" id="family-radio-btn">
        <input type="radio" class="toggle-input" name="family" id="family-yes" checked>
        <label for="family-yes"  class="toggle-label toggle-label-off">Yes</label>
        <input type="radio" class="toggle-input" name="family" id="family-no">
        <label for="family-no" class="toggle-label toggle-label-on">No</label>
        <span class="toggle-selection"></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Does the trick, thank you. So how does your modified click event correct this?

Comment: instead of selecting `div` we need to get the `click` event of `input`

Answer (score 2):

you're having problems with event bubbling. Clicking on a label generates two clicks: one on label and another on input.

I'd suggest you to handle the radio button click with this change in your javascript:

```
$('input[name="family"]').click(function() {
  if($(this).attr('checked')) {
    console.log('yes');
  } else {
    console.log('no');
  }
});
```

Wish u luck

Answer (score 1):

You are using click event on parent div that contain both radio button yes and no. So when you click on any button it will trigger click event two time one for label and one for input.

So you need to bind click event on input radio only.

Try this :

```js
$(function(){

    $('.toggle-input').click(function () {
       // e.preventDefault();
        if ($('#family-yes').is(":checked")) {
            alert("yes");
        }
        else
        {
            alert("no");
        }
    });
});
```

```css
.toggle {
  position: relative;
  height: 34px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  background: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
.toggle .toggle-input {
  display: none;
}
.toggle .toggle-input:checked + .toggle-label {
  color: #ffffff;
}
.toggle .toggle-input:checked + .toggle-label-on ~ .toggle-selection {
  left: 49%;
}
.toggle .toggle-label {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  line-height: 32px;
  color: #555555;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: normal;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.toggle .toggle-label.toggle-label-off {
  padding-left: 2px;
}
.toggle .toggle-label.toggle-label-on {
  padding-right: 2px;
}
.toggle .toggle-selection {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 2px;
  left: 2px;
  display: block;
  width: 50%;
  height: 28px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: #0071bc;
  -webkit-transition: left 0.15s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: left 0.15s ease-out;
  -ms-transition: left 0.15s ease-out;
  -o-transition: left 0.15s ease-out;
  transition: left 0.15s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="toggle" id="family-radio-btn">
        <input type="radio" class="toggle-input" name="family" id="family-yes" checked>
        <label for="family-yes" class="toggle-label toggle-label-off">Yes</label>
        <input type="radio" class="toggle-input" name="family" id="family-no">
        <label for="family-no" class="toggle-label toggle-label-on">No</label>
        <span class="toggle-selection"></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this:

```
$('#family-radio-btn').click(function () {
    if ($('#family-yes').is(":checked")) {
        alert("yes");
    }
    else
    {
        alert("no");
    }
});
```